# Two inserts simultaniously

Tags: mysql, myisam

What would happen if I was to insert say 1000 rows (taking 20 seconds, but one query). After 2 seconds someone else tried to insert a row at the same location e.g.

```
20secondquery
1|yellow
2|blue
3|green
4|violet

2secondquery
4|blue
```

Would their row be inserted or would it queue until my insert was finished?
(MyISAM)

Comment: never seen someone choosing violet as the 4th color :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what sort of transactions and/or locking you're using.

If someone issues a single big INSERT statement, that will complete atomically as a single operation. If they are spamming a whole bunch of INSERTS, then the secondquery will fall in between those.

You need to look into [Table Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) to control this sort of thing.

```
LOCK TABLES widgets WRITE;
INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES ('Widget A');
INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES ('Widget B');
INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES ('Widget C');
INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES ('Widget D');
INSERT INTO widgets (name) VALUES ('Widget E');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

For the time between the `LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES` nothing else will be able to read or write to the table.

Comment: OP said "MyISAM" (just barely).

Comment: Good spot, I missed that. Although, I would recommend against relying too much on underlying storage-engine characteristics, and being explicit wherever possible. Next week client may move to InnoDB and then all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

MyISAM uses table level locking. The other insert has to wait

Comment: +1  This is the answer, yet you might want to clarify that. See [adrien's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449035/two-inserts-simultaniously/10449092#10449092).

Comment: :/ ive just started reading high performance mySql and thats the best clear shot i can give

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is : it depends :)

It depends on your MySQL server configuration (value of `concurrent_insert` for instance) and of the query you are running to insert your data.

[Documentation on concurrent inserts for MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html)

Comment: +1 This is important for the OP to understand, yet OP said "insert a row in the same location".